# Why does this node.js loop run slowly after 112050 iterations?

Tags: node.js, performance, loops, file-io, io

I was playing around with node.js and I found that this simple program is running incredibly slowly, and I didn't even wait around to see how long it took after 3 minutes had passed.

```
var fs = require ('fs')
var s = fs.createWriteStream("test.txt");
for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
      s.write(i+"\n");
s.end()
```

I experimented using different values, and found that while 1-112050 takes 3 seconds, 1-112051 takes over a minute. This sudden dropoff is strange. The same program in python, or the equivalent shell script 'seq 1 112051` runs in a reasonable amount of time (0-2 seconds).

Note that this node.js app runs much faster:

```
var fs = require('fs')
     , s = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) s.push(i.toString())
s.push('')
fs.writeFile('UIDs.txt', s.join('\n'), 'utf8')
```

Can anyone explain to me why node.js behaves this way, and why the dropoff is so sudden?

Comment: I can confirm this is happening on my Linux VM: `0m2.372s` vs `1m0.039s`. The fact that this number is so round makes me think it might be a timeout deep inside the write stream. I'll look a bit more into it.

Comment: Also, when using `strace`, it slows down significantly in the first case - to `0m7.259s` but by the same amount in the second case - `1m6.462s`, making me suspect that even further.

Comment: Is the *size* of the data directly related to the degenerate performance (and if so, what is the size, in bytes) or is it the *number* of `write` calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a buffer that gets filled up. Each write will return `true` or `false` depending on the state of the kernel buffer.

If you start listen to the return code and use the [drain](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) event, it will at least be consistant in speed.

```
var fs = require ('fs') 

function runTest(stop) {
  var s = fs.createWriteStream("test.txt");
  var startTime = Date.now();
  var c = 1;
  function doIt() {
    while (++c <= stop) {
      if (!s.write(c+"\n")) {
        s.once('drain', doIt);
        return;
      }
    }

    s.end();
    var diffTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    console.log(stop+': took '+diffTime+'ms, per write: '+(diffTime/stop)+'ms')
  }

  doIt();
}

runTest(10000);
runTest(100000);
runTest(1000000);
runTest(10000000);
runTest(100000000);
```

Output:

```
$ node test.js
10000: took 717ms, per write: 0.0717ms
100000: took 5818ms, per write: 0.05818ms
1000000: took 42902ms, per write: 0.042902ms
10000000: took 331583ms, per write: 0.0331583ms
100000000: took 2542195ms, per write: 0.02542195ms
```

Comment: These tests interleave. As soon as the first `runTest(10000)` hits `s.once('drain', doIt);`, the next `runTest(100000)` already starts running. You can verify this by inserting `console.log('Testing '+stop+'...');` at the top of the function.

Answer (score 13):

This happens because `for` cycle is synchronous, but `Writable.write()` is not. For your example `s.write` creates **one million** chunks queue. That causes more than **one million** function calls ([like this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1614)) to process this queue. So, `Writable.write` is not designed for small chunks. You can [check sources](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L121) of `Writable.write` to get more info about it.

Comment: Fair enough, but why is it that a difference of just one call over 112050 makes the processing time jump from 3 seconds to over a minute?

Comment: @TonyBiondo, Could be just about anything... likely related to the buffer size of *something* in the IO chain.  Experiment.

Comment: Thanks to this, I queued my output and only called `write` for every millionth item, which sped things up considerably :)

Answer (score -3):

I believe this may be environment specific, In what context are you coding this?
eg, initially I thought it was for a website, but it involves writing files which throws me off.

Otherwise, working with file systems works funny depending on implementations, I'm not one to blame programming languages but I really don't know how javascript treats file IO on your particular system, performance in file IO is a science in its own right, possibly as old as computer science itself.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with the node.js environment *at all*, you should probably just leave this question alone.